# C++ Rotating 2D Shape List

Tags: c++, list, rotation, shapes

I am having a bit of an issue with rotating a shape with given degrees.

```
void Shape::rotate(double degrees)
{
    // rotates the vertices of a shape by a specified angle in degrees

    int x, y, xx, yy;
    double radians;

    x = centroid.getX();
    y = centroid.getY();
    vertices.push_back(Vertex(x, y));

    x = vertices.back().getX() - centroid.getX();
    y = vertices.back().getY() - centroid.getY();

    radians = (degrees * PI) / 180;
    xx = round(x * cos(radians) - y * sin(radians));
    yy = round(y * cos(radians) + x * sin(radians));
    xx = xx + centroid.getX();
    yy = yy + centroid.getY();
    vertices.push_back(Vertex(xx, yy));

    radians = (degrees * PI) / 180;
    xx = round(x * cos(radians) - y * sin(radians));
    yy = round(y * cos(radians) + x * sin(radians));
    xx = xx + centroid.getX();
    yy = yy + centroid.getY();
    vertices.push_back(Vertex(xx, yy));

    radians = (degrees * PI) / 180;
    xx = round(x * cos(radians) - y * sin(radians));
    yy = round(y * cos(radians) + x * sin(radians));
    xx = xx + centroid.getX();
    yy = yy + centroid.getY();
    vertices.push_back(Vertex(xx, yy));
}
```

but the output i get is this:

[Messed up rhombus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0SWR.jpg)

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What was the original shape?

Comment: It was a rhombus(diamond) the only new thing after the code executes is the 90 degree line through the centre of the shape that has appeared

Comment: Did you Step-Over your code to see what is exactly happening logic wise?

Comment: I did but I havent been able to come up with a solution to why its happening

Comment: It seems you try to modify `vertices` vector, but do not remove old vertices from it. Is it intended behaviour?

Comment: no the intended behavior is to rotate the shape by a given set of degrees such as 50 degrees and then redraw the new shape